# Submitting CSR to Microsoft CA from linux bash best practice

Tags: linux, active-directory, openssl, certificate-authority, x509

Similar questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283476/submitting-base64-csr-to-a-microsoft-ca-via-curl

The link above presents an answer but it is far too complicated for me.

Below is an example that would work if our CA public and private key are in the same directory, on a linux machine. Lets assume our .cnf is setup correctly and CA has been created. These commands do not work, but close enough to get the idea:

Step 1: generate .csr and .key and from .cnf

```
openssl req -new -keyout example.key -out example.csr -config example.cnf
```

Step 2: sign request

```
openssl x509 -req -in ./example.csr -CA ./ca.cer -CAkey ./ca.key -out example.cer  ...
```

I would like to complete Step 2 by sending the request to a windows CA from the linux machine. What do I need to do this?

I'm aware this exists for non-domain services, but it is not applicable here. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9063.active-directory-certificate-services-ad-cs-network-device-enrollment-service-ndes.aspx